# How to parse folders of version numbers and extract the highest

Tags: bash, download, comparison, version, directory-structure

Lets say there's the following structure in an SVN repository :

- http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/all-in-one-seo-pack/branches/1.6.13/
- http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/all-in-one-seo-pack/branches/1.6.12/
- http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/all-in-one-seo-pack/branches/1.5.2/

etc.

I'd like to do the following with a bash script :

1. go through all the subdirectories of /branches
2. find the highest version number
3. download it

I'm new to bash, the download part is easy, but I'm stuck on the folder name extraction and comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your branches can be simply sorted, you can use something like this :

```
svn list http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/all-in-one-seo-pack/branches | sort | tail -n 1
>>> 1.6.13/
```

Comment: @Cédric Julien, thanks, what does the `1.6.13` mean at the end of your code ?

Comment: @Cédric Julien, ah ok, I thought it was part of the command.. :/ Is there a way to do the same without having to install svn ?

Comment: @mike23 : then how do you retrieve the branches ? via a http access ?

Comment: @Cédric Julien, I don't know, in PHP you can recursively read folder names, is that not possible in bash scripting?

Comment: @mike23 : for a subversion repository, it's really easier to use svn ;)